# Plot two time series in one figure(MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, plot, time-series

Suppose that we have these two series:

```
First_Series = [1, 1200; 2,1300; 3,100; 5,267;  6,2674; 7,1346];
Second_Series = [8, 1340; 9,2100; 10,1100];
```

In both series first column is x-axis and second column is y-axis. I want these two series in a same line-plot with different colors.

Comment: If Ray's answer is not what you expect, please describe exactly what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Call `figure`;  This creates a window to plot the graph
2. Call `plot` on the first one, this will plot the first series
3. Issue the command `hold on;` this holds the previously  plotted graph window
4. Plot the second series--it will plot on the held graph

When you issue the command `hold off;`  it will release the graph window.  New plots will go to a new graph window.

Here's an example with your data set plotting red and green lines for the two series:

```
 figure;
 plot(First_Series(:,1), First_Series(:,2), 'r');
 hold on;
 plot(Second_Series(:,1), Second_Series(:,2), 'g');
 hold off;
```

You should get the following result:
[image]

Comment: @user2991243  I added an example.  Try it and see if you get a single graph with 2 lines plotted

Comment: The second series is after first series. check first column in both series.

Comment: @user2991243 I get what you mean, I updated my answer so they are properly positioned.

Comment: @user2991243 also added the colors red and green to the different series

Comment: If you wish to continue the series from where you left of, try this: `A = [First_Series;Second_Series]; plot(A)`

Comment: @noumenal Can you specify different colors for the two series when you combine them to a single matrix?  That looks like it combines them into a single series.

Comment: Note that using `hold on` and `hold off` instead of just `hold` makes the action clearer.

Comment: Correction, I meant: `plot(A(:,1), A(:,2))`. I am not sure Ray if piecewise functions can be colored. The current code, however, does not give a continuous line plot. Perhaps this is an advantage.

Comment: @noumenal The OP needs to clarify where the *border* (changing colors) should be. It's pretty easy to include the last point of the first series to the second series thus forming a continuous line. I think it's the best way to draw separate plots for the colors because it's not directly possible to have multiple colors in a single `line`-object.